# how to show a category from a CPT?

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type called 'seasons' and in there i have 3 categories (summer,winter and spring.)

I want to show 10 random post from the winter category on a page.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

[WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) is the solution to your problem.

Go through the available [parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters). Just add a query and a loop in your page template and you are good to go.

Ex.

```
$args = array(
'category_name' => 'winter',
'orderby' => 'rand',
'posts_per_page' => 10
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The loop starts here:

```
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
```

and ends here:

```
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the custom post type in the $args array in the code above by Rohit:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'seasons', //ADD THIS
    'category_name' => 'winter'
    );
```